# Generating a fixed number

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I have a fixed number $a$. Now using $a$ I need to construct a number $b$ such that $0.99\leq b\leq 1$. Is there any mathematical formulation of such a construction that looks random. The generation of such a number should be deterministic. can somebody hint at any algorithms

Comment: If you want it to look random, I'd go for something like $.995 +.005\times \sin \left(e^a\right)$ where you can replace $e^a$ with other functions to get the "look" you want.

Comment: .998413267543212

Comment: What are you using this for? (There's a notable difference here between "this is an internal value in a video game" and "this is part of a cryptography scheme")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For example $\,b=0.99 + \dfrac{\sin^2(\lambda a)}{100}\,$, with $\,\lambda \in \mathbb{R}\,$ adjusted for the range of $\,a\,$.

Comment: What do you mean by range of a

Comment: @Upstart You didn't say what values $\,a\,$ can take. If it's an arbitrary real number then you can leave $\,\lambda=1\,$ (or, in fact, choose *any* $\,\lambda \ne 0\,$). However, if $\,a \in [a_{min}, a_{max}]\,$ then you would probably choose $\,\lambda\,$ so that the argument of the $\,\sin\,$ covers many enough periods of $\,2 \pi\,$ as to make it look "random".

Comment: Oh yes i do have a range $a\in [0,255]$

Comment: @Upstart $\,\lambda = 1\,$ is probably "good enough" for that range. You'll need to try some test runs and evaluate "good enough" for the particular purpose.

Comment: With using just $\sin^2$ I would expect some patterns emerging yet.  But maybe your sample of $[0, 255]$ is small enough to avoid that.

Comment: @Alfe The resulting distribution is not uniform, so there would be a "pattern" in that sense, indeed. But the question leaves it vague what the purpose/application/requirements of the exercise are.

Answer (score 8):

The provided value, $a$, is your ***seed value***.

The algorithm you want is a [pseudo-random number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) (PRNG).  Note that pseudo-random number generators are explicitly deterministic; they merely appear random.

Depending on how random you need it to look, you may want to use a [cryptographically secure PRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator).  Such an algorithm, if truly cryptographically secure, should pretty much look random as far as any human-like observer could tell (though its operation may be plain and obvious to super-human observers, e.g. advanced aliens or deities; can't do much there).

Most PRNG's are designed to produce a bit-array (a bunch of $\left\{0,~1\right\}$ values) given a seed.  If $a$ is real $\left(a\in\mathbb{R}\right)$, then that bit-array may contain arbitrarily many bits.  Typically, the bit-array's defined such that each bit is pseudo-unrelated to the others, such that can be assumed to be mutually independent.

Then, it's just a matter of mapping the bit-array to numeric values.  You might do this by interpreting the bit array as a serialization of a [binary real](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Representing_real_numbers) $\in{\left[0.9,1\right]}$.

Answer (score 6):

What about 
$$0.99+\frac1{100(1+a^2)}?$$